# How to Make Xcode Recognize Morph Targets in a DAE File Imported from Blender?

Tags: xcode, scenekit, arkit, blender, 3d-modelling

I'm working on a project in Xcode where I need to use a 3D model with multiple morph targets (shape keys in Blender) for animations. The model, specifically the Wolf3D_Head node, contains dozens of morph targets which are crucial for my project. Here's what I've done so far:

I verified the morph targets in Blender (I can see all the morph targets correctly when opening both the original .glb file and the converted .dae file in Blender). Here's a screenshot from Blender showing the morph targets.
[image: https://api.monosnap.com/file/download?id=nZIaZT63O1Jzf5Nvv1KHaQC7oIbzUF]

Given that Xcode does not support .glb file format directly, I converted the model to .dae format, aiming to use it in my Xcode project.
After importing the .dae file into Xcode, I noticed that Xcode does not show any morph targets for the Wolf3D_Head node or any other node in the model. Here's a screenshot of Xcode showing no geometry morphers.
[image]
I've already attempted using tools like ColladaMorphAdjuster and another version by JakeHoldom to adjust the .dae file, hoping Xcode would recognize the morph targets, but it didn't resolve the issue.

My question is: How can I make Xcode recognize and display the morph targets present in the .dae file exported from Blender? Is there a specific process or tool that I need to use to ensure Xcode properly imports all the morph target information from a .dae file?

Tools tried: https://github.com/JonAllee/ColladaMorphAdjuster, https://github.com/JakeHoldom/ColladaMorphAdjuster

Thanks in advance!